# Storing and retrieving HTML Blob video clip on Node.js server

Tags: jquery, node.js, html, video, blob

I am developing a WebRTC application which uses Node.js to establish a connection between two clients, using [RTCMulticonnection](http://www.rtcmulticonnection.org/docs/). It is a one-way video, two-way audio connection. The client receiving the video stream has the functionality to store clips which are created from the video stream. Currently, I have code which enables the clips to be created in the form of an HTML blob. The information stored within the blob needs to be captured and stored in a file locally on the Node.js server.

**UPLOADING**

Currently, I am uploading the blob via jQuery ajax request to the server using a FormData object, using the [formidable](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable) module. The files are being stored as binary files with no file extension, rather than MP4 or other similar video formats. What I need is a way to either convert the FormData blob to a video file format and store it locally (the blob video on the HTML page is of 'video/webm' format) or a way to utilise this binary file for download, so it can later be displayed as a video on the client side.

**Client-side**

```
connection.streams[recStreamId].stopRecording(function (blob) {

            var form = document.createElement('form');
            var mediaElement = document.createElement('video');
            mediaElement.autoplay = false;
            mediaElement.controls = true;
            mediaElement.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob.video);
            mediaElement.style.width= '100%';
            form.appendChild(mediaElement);
            document.getElementById("saved-videos").appendChild(form);


            var filename = Date.now();

            uploadToServer({cid: cid, vidpath: filename, fname: "video", blob: blob.video});
            uploadToServer({cid: cid, vidpath: filename, fname: "audio", blob: blob.audio});

            return true;

        }, {audio: true, video: true});
```

**Server-side**

```
var mkdirp = require('mkdirp');
var formidable = require('formidable');

var app = protocol.createServer(options, function (req, res) {

var router = {
    post: {},
    get: {}
};

router.post['/upload_video'] = function(req, res){

    console.log("Uploading");

    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

    var path;
    var fname;
    var vid;
    var vidpath;

    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files){
        if (err)
            res.writeHead(err.status, err.headers);
            res.end();

        cid = fields.cid;
        vidpath = fields.vidpath;
        fname = fields.fname;
        vid = files.data;

        console.log(fields);
    });

    form.on('end', function(){

        //Directory specific to the user with ID=cid
        path = videoPath+cid+"/";

        //If the directory does not already exist, create it
        mkdirp(path, function(err) { 
            if (err){
                res.writeHead(err.status, err.headers);
                res.end();
            }

            path = path + vidpath + "/";

            mkdirp(path, function(err){
                if (err){
                    res.writeHead(err.status, err.headers);
                    res.end();
                }

                console.log(vid);

                fs.copy(vid.path, path + fname, function(err) {  
                    if (err){
                        res.writeHead(err.status, err.headers);
                        res.end();
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    });
}
}
```

The files are successfully being stored on the server side. If i open up one of the video files in the browser, the video is played successfully. This is not a mandatory feature since they will never be opened from server side, however they need to be retrievable and displayed on client-side.

**DOWNLOADING**

I am currently downloading these files using fs.readfile. Since this blob has both a video and audio component, one blob is stored to the server in the following format:

```
__dirname + userid + "/" + videoid + "/video" // video component
__dirname + userid + "/" + videoid + "/audio" // audio component

//Example - C:/project/videos/user4/video2/video
//Example - C:/project/videos/user4/video2/audio
```

**Server-side**

These files are being downloaded using fs.readFile, and the returned buffer is sent to the client via the HTTP response.

```
router.get['/downloadVideo'] = function(req, res){
    var query = url.parse(req.url, true).query;

    var response = {query: query};

    if (query.video == "true") query.video = true;
    if (query.video == "false") query.video = false;
    if (query.audio == "true") query.audio = true;
    if (query.audio == "false") query.audio = false;

    var num_remaining = 0;
    if (query.audio) num_remaining++;
    if (query.video) num_remaining++;

    if (query.video){
        fs.readFile(videoPath + query.cid + "/" + query.dir + "/video", function(err, buf){

            console.log("Downloading " + query.dir + "/video");

            num_remaining--;

            response.videobuf = buf;

            if (num_remaining == 0)
                res.end(JSON.stringify(response));
        });
    }

    if (query.audio){
        fs.readFile(videoPath + query.cid + "/" + query.dir + "/audio", function(err, buf){

            console.log("Downloading " + query.dir + "/audio");

            num_remaining--;

            response.audiobuf = buf;

            if (num_remaining == 0)
                res.end(JSON.stringify(response));
        });
    }
}
```

**Client-side**

The videos are downloaded using jQuery and ajax. The data object in displayVideo() contains two buffers - videobuf and audiobuf - which are the buffers from the file downloaded via fs.readFile(). This is where the problem lies. The blob being created is successfully created but the data is not correct to the extent that a video is displayed. The video element is created but the video is not in the right format.

```
function downloadVideos(data){
    var paths = JSON.parse(data).data;

    console.log(paths);
    for (var p in paths){
        var path = paths[p];

        var query = ""; 
        query += "?dir="+path.dir;
        query += "&video="+path.video;
        query += "&audio="+path.audio;
        query += "&cid="+cid;

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: url + "/downloadVideo"+query,
            data: {}
        }).done(displayVideo);
    }
}

function displayVideo(data, textStatus, response){
    var result = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(result);

    var blob = new Blob(result.videobuf.data, {type: "video/webm"});

    console.log(blob);

    var mediaElement = document.createElement('video');
    mediaElement.id = result.query.dir;
    mediaElement.autoplay = false;
    mediaElement.controls = true;
    mediaElement.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    mediaElement.style.width= '100%';
    document.getElementById("saved-videos").appendChild(mediaElement);
}
```

I understand that this is a lot of information, I wanted to include as much detail as possible so that it would be clear where all of my functionality lies and how I've done everything. If anything else is required please let me know, but I think this should've covered everything.